# First 8 bytes are always wrong when downloading a file from my script

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have a Mojolicious Lite script that "gives out" an executable file (user can download the file from the script's URL). I keep encoded data in an inline template in DATA section, then encode it and render_data.

```
get '/download' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    my $hex_data = $self->render_partial( 'TestEXE' );
    my $bin_data;
    while( $hex_data =~ /([^\n]+)\n?/g ) {
        $bin_data .= pack "H".(length $1), $1;
    }

    my $headers = Mojo::Headers->new; 
    $headers->add( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-download;name=Test.exe' );
    $headers->add( 'Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=Test.exe' );
    $headers->add( 'Content-Description', 'File Transfer');

    $self->res->content->headers($headers);
    $self->render_data( $bin_data ); 
};

__DATA__

@@ TestEXE.html.ep
4d5a90000300000004000000ffff0000b8000000000000004000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b0000000
0e1fba0e00b409cd21b8014ccd21546836362070726f6772616d2063616e6e6f
....
```

When I run this locally (via built in webserver on http://127.0.0.1:3000/, Win7) I get the correct file (size and contents). But when I run it in CGI mode on shared hosting (Linux), it comes back with correct size, but first 8 bytes of the file are always incorrect (and always different). The rest of the file is correct.

If in my sub i specify `$hex_data` instead of `$bin_data` I get what suppose to be there.

I'm at lost.

Comment: My first guess would be you have CRLF in your file.  Try using only Unix line endings (LF).

Comment: cjm, that what I thought, but firstly, my FTP client does automatic conversion, and I then did manually convert it before uploading just in case.. with the same result. besides, it didn't explain to me why bytes don't corrupt if I don't "encode" the data :-/ but if the `tempire`'s suggestions work I'll be happy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*render_partial* isn't what you want.

First, [re-encode the executable in base64 format](https://superuser.com/a/133253/34808), and specify that the template is base64 encoded (This is assuming hex is not a requirement for your app):

```
@@ template-name (base64)
```

Also, you don't actually need a controller method at all.  Mojolicious will handle the process for you - all you have to do is appropriately name the template.

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ Test.exe (base64)
...
```

http://127.0.0.1:3000/Test.exe will then download the file.

-

If you still want to use a controller method for app-specific concerns, get the data template specifically:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/download' => sub {
    my $self = shift;

    # http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Renderer.pm#get_data_template
    my $data = $self->app->renderer->get_data_template({}, 'Test.exe');

    # Replace content-disposition instead of adding it, 
    # to prevent duplication from elsewhere in the app
    $self->res->headers->header(
        'Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename=name.exe');

    $self->render_data($data);
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ Test.exe (base64)
...
```

http://127.0.0.1:3000/download will get the template, set the header, and then download it as name.exe.

Comment: Umm, base64 is not hexadecimal (although a string of hexadecimal digits is valid base64 if it has the right number of digits, it has a completely different meaning).  Unless you reencode Test.exe in base64, you'll be serving a completely different file.

Comment: Indeed; I assumed that his hex solution was a hack to get render_partial output in an acceptable format.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! i will try it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: the problem seems to be in me using old version of Mojolicious. because most shared hostings still provide Perl 5.8 we are limited to pre-2.0 versions :( But thank you very much for your reply, I learned something new

Comment: Shared hosting!  It's 2012, use heroku :)  But, if you insist on using outdated versions of Perl, https://github.com/jamadam/mojo-legacy.